# FCM Push Notification error InvalidRegistration and NotRegistered on IOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to send a Push Notification using the FCM. The operation works fine for Android. But, when I try to send it to IOS the first response is an error of type "InvalidRegistration" and the next errors are of type "NotRegistered".

I'm using the following HTTP body:

```
{
    "registration_ids": [
        "my_registration_id"
    ],
    "collapse_key": "My collapse key",
    "data": {
        "body": "Test body",
        "title": "Test Push",
        "action": "My Screen",
        "id": 309556505
    },
    "delay_while_idle": false,
    "time_to_live": 43200,
    "content_available": false,
    "priority": "high"
}
```

Comment: You can try to get some clues from here https://gitmemory.com/issue/flutter/flutter/30486/496970155 Seems to be a common configuration issue on the web service side, you might try to delete the app, clear cache, remove the device from the FCM registered devices list, and try again

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it.